# Vue.js - Stop propagation for multiple event handlers

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, stoppropagation

I have a component that emits an `showSelection` event on click but also retains the click event handler given to it by its parent.

```
<template>
    <section class="base-input peudo-select">
        <input 
            v-bind="$attrs"
            type="text"
            readonly
            v-on="listeners"
            @dblclick.prevent.stop
        />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    ...
    computed:{
        listeners(){
            return {
                ...this.$listeners,
                input: event => this.$emit('input', event.target.value),
                click: [
                    this.$listeners.click, // Always put the parent given handler first.
                    event => this.$emit('showSelection', event),
                ],
            }
        }
    }
    ...
};
</script>
```

And on its parent component, i have this.

```
<template>
    <section class="main-page">
        <pseudo-select-input
            tooltip="How would you like to pay?"
            placeholder="Source of Fund"
            @click="selectInputClicked($event)"
            @showSelection="showSelection"
        />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        selectInputClicked(e) {
            console.log('stopping propagation');
            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        showSelection() {
            console.log('starting selection');
        },
    },
    ...
};
</script>
```

When try to run the code, both logs are are shown even when `selectInputClicked` tried stopping the propagation.

I'm well aware of `event.stop` but I don't want it to always stop the propagation. I will be having conditions whether it should stop propagation (e.g. a previous input is empty).

No, I don't need to do `click.native` since i'm "tunneling" the component's event listeners to the input element (see `computed`->`listeners` and `v-on="listeners"`).

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/suj95omn/)

> The fiddle is not exactly the same as above but it has the same idea.

Update #1:

> Throwing an exception on the first handler stops the propagation to the next. For obvious reasons. it is not good enough. I'll save it as a last resort.

Comment: @palaѕн done, i added a fiddle link